# Infinite loop? Help debug this R code

Tags: r, loops

Here's my code..

```
T1=matrix(nrow=1000,ncol=1)
T2=matrix(nrow=1000,ncol=1)

X1=matrix(nrow=6,ncol=1)
X2=matrix(nrow=6,ncol=1)

n1=1
n2=2
while((n1<=5)||(n2<=5))
{ 
  t=t+rexp(1,rate=4.3)
  u=runif(1,0,1)
  if(u<=0.25) 
   {
     X1[n1]=t
    n1=n1+1
   }
  if(u>0.25)
  {
   X2[n2]=t
   n2=n2+1
  }
}
```

It just keeps processing it and doesn't stop. I can't proceed. I think it's running an infinite loop but i am not sure.
Without the while it works fine and the termination condition definitely gets attained but then why is it not working. Help please.
(Btw i have 16GB ram so it's not that my PC is slow or old... I have waited long enough and it still kept on processing hence i think it's an infinite loop)

Comment: How about `&&` instead of `||`? What guarantees both exceed value of 5?

Comment: where's `t` defined?

Comment: what are `T1` and `T2` doing here?

Answer (score 0):

This **may** run indefinitely **if** either

1. `u` is always `<= 0.25`, or
2. `u` is always `> 0.25`.

In case **1**, `n2` never changes and so the `while` condition never exits. In case **2**, `n1` never changes and so the `while` condition never exits.

This is because you're testing if either `n1` **or** `n2` are less than 5. In either case, one of them is always less than 5.

You probably wan to use `while((n1 <= 5) & (n2 <= 5))` ?

---

Other comments:

- you haven't defined `t`
- I can't see what `T1` or `T2` do here